# How to write print statement to a text file in Python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary and I am trying to use the key value pairs to generate a print statment and write to a text file.

```
f= open("queries.txt","w+")
for id, summary in map_of_values.items():
    f.write("UPDATE dbo.job SET summary=%s WHERE id=%s \n",(summary, id))
f.close()
```

There are around 20,000 key value pairs. I am getting the following error. How to achieve it?

> TypeError: write() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f.write("UPDATE dbo.job SET summary=%s WHERE id=%s \n",(summary, id))
```

should be

```
f.write("UPDATE dbo.job SET summary=%s WHERE id=%s \n" % (summary, id))
```

notice the "%"